# Convert parameter in Select statement

Tags: stored-procedures, expression

I am trying to convert a date parameter in my select statement but i wanted to format it and currently it is not accepting how i have it written -- Any advice would be appreciated

```
SELECT @cases = COALESCE(@cases+ @linebreak + C.CaseNumber, C.CaseNumber)+"-"+CT.[Description]+"-"+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@assignment,100)AS A.DateOn
```

This is how i had it before the formatting and it was converting and working fine:

```
SELECT @cases = COALESCE(@cases+ @linebreak + C.CaseNumber, C.CaseNumber)+"-"+CT.[Description]+"-"+CONVERT(VARCHAR, A.DateOn)
```

Not sure if more information will be needed or not but let me know.

Comment: What are trying to do? Input and Outputs please. If this isn't working, how are we meant to guess what it is meant to do...

Comment: @ gbn sorry if i wasn't clear - the select statement is to give an output of a NUMBER - DESCRIPTION - DATE. My current output is 12341 - Adoption - Apr 14,2010. I want the output to be: 12341 - Adoption - 4/14/2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Guessing*, your last bit should be

```
...+CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.DateOn,101)
```

Where does @assignment come from? Your unformatted code doesn't mention it...

Note (after question comment) 4/14/2010 is harder to do than 04/14/2010. You have to evaluate day, month and year separately to remove leading zeros